# Detect incoming PHP post, save file

Tags: c#, php, post, file-transfer

Currently there is a server set up to post zlib files to another server : (Here is the C# code for that)

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://server-ip-here/postlistener?filename=filename.zlib");
req.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
req.Method = "POST";
req.Accept = "application/xml";
req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
req.Proxy = new WebProxy();

filename = "filename.dat";
byte[] postData = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
stream.Flush();
stream.Close();

req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(responseHandler), this);
```

Need to write some php on a different server so that when this specific IP posts stuff to me (aka when server 192. something or other posts to my server IP) I need to be able to

- a) Detect that a POST is being made
- b) Check it is by a whitelisted IP
- c) Download the POST data (which should be binary) and save it as whatever its name is in the post (need to accept filename in URL: . www.blah.com/upload?filename=somefile_1234_12389126496129684790.zlib)

However being new ish to PHP this is what my research so far has told me:

- a) Use this code to see if the request is a post

  `if '($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  // …
  }`
- b) use: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
- c) No real idea.

Also not entirely sure how to string these parts together. Any ideas how I can go about listening for POSTs being sent from that IP, then downloading the file that is being posted?

Also really not sure how to set my php page up to be able to do:

`/postlistener?filename=filename.zlib`

I believe the postlistener part is my page, and somehow that page is supposed to get a file also? TH=his is my understanding, have taken over this project for someone else in the company, and of course there is no documentation to go with it. Any help would be big help, thanks.

Comment: To detect if there is a POST, then to download all the data in the post depending on the name of the post.

Comment: Crap I edited your comment instead of replying...

Comment: No, I deleted it, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will listen for any POST data, and then put the post variable name into an array.

```
    <?

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '*IPADDRESS*') {
          $posts = array();
          foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
               echo "{$key} = {$value}\r\n";
               array_push($posts,$key);
          }
      }
}

print_r($posts);
?>
```

After that you can loop through the `$posts` array and download all the things.

Comment: for modifying this so it only works if the post is from a specific IP I would just modify the if statement to also check if the http referer is correct?

Comment: Okay thanks, will go do some research into downloading. I assume I would put second loop right after the first one finishes to download?

Comment: Yes, I would put a second loop right after the first loop. Make sure it's inside the `{ }` for the $_SERVER variable.

Comment: Also, there is no way to test if this works without a the download part? I use fiddler to simulate a POST being sent, but obviously the page wont auto reload with the print_r($posts); Since this page will never actually be viewed, its all done by one server to another server automatically.

Comment: You could try to make php create a file when it gets the post, and fill that file with the POST data? I'm not sure of how much access you have etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110654/discussion-between-lain-and-grumpycrouton).